# Correct way to insert taxonomies on page insert

Tags: custom-taxonomy

```
        $page = array(
            'post_title'   => 'New Job',
            'post_name'    => 'new-job',
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status'  => 'publish',
            'post_author'  => 1,
            'post_type'    => 'jobs',
            'tax_input'    => array (
                'status' => 'system'
            )
        );

        wp_insert_post( $page );
```

This doesn't work. I am trying to create post and relate it to my custom term in my custom taxonomy.

Taxonomy: status

Term: system

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you can't use the term slug (for obvious reason of possible duplicate slugs *face palm*) you need to use the terms ID.

```
        $term_id = term_exists( 'system', 'status' );

        $page = array(
            'post_title'   => 'New Job',
            'post_name'    => 'new-job',
            'post_content' => '',
            'post_status'  => 'publish',
            'post_author'  => 1,
            'post_type'    => 'jobs',
            'tax_input'    => array (
                'status' => array ( (int)$term_id["term_id"] )
            )
        );

        wp_insert_post( $page );
```